# Generating a PowerSet and Returning It As A List

Tags: prolog

I'm currently having trouble generating a power set given a set, example [1,2,3], and populating a list of lists. I'm completely novice at Prolog, and was able to generate powersets as such, but it is recursive and returns them one by one.

```
powerset([], []).
powerset([E|Tail], [E|OtherTail]) :-
    powerset(Tail, OtherTail).
powerset([_|Tail], OtherTail) :-
    powerset(Tail, OtherTail).
```

I'm trying to get it all into one list: `Example [1,2] -> [[1], [2], [1,2], []]`

Comment: Nothing wrong with a recursive solution that provides each solution on backtracking. That's the bread and butter of Prolog. If you then want all the solutions in a list, use `findall/3`.

Comment: in [tag:dcg], `pset([A|B]) --> ([A] ; []), pset(B). pset([]) --> [].`